# Sentence phrasing 'Please don't punish/scold/penalize'

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english

Situation: I technician came to my house for installation/demo or Refrigerator.
He was good but forgot to install a 'rat mesh' ( protect machine from rats). 
 I called customer care to inform the incident. I did not want the company to punish/scold/penalize the technician as he was professional.

I know following options but somehow they are not perfect fit although '2' is close.

1. Please do not scold technician as he was otherwise good
2. Please do not punish or penalize him as he was otherwise good
3. Suggest any other

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, ***call down***

> : reprimand : *called down for being late*; *I was called down by my supervisor for not catching the accounting error sooner.*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call%20down)

In your example,

> *Please don't call down the technician as he was otherwise good.*

Comment: You would? I wouldn't. The OED calls it "*colloq.* (chiefly *N. Amer.*)" And even in North American, it's definitely informal and, I suspect, regional.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go with option 2 but don't say "punish or penalise". Instead, choose between the two.